# How to create a new array based on the selected value from an existiing array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of books which comes from an API.I want to filter the books array and put the selected book on a new array when the user selects a value from the dropdown.So,my book will have a dropdown which will have 3 values : 1)Currently Reading 2) Want to Read and  3) Read. Now I have created 3 arrays in my react state. So,when the user selects a value from the dropdown, it moves the book to the array defined for it.I have a handleChange() function for that purpose which will get the value of the array but I am not able to figure out how to remove the book selected from the books array and move it to the selected option array. So how do I filter out the books array  based on the condition and put it to the new array.

Updated BooksList Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BooksList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={
        showSearchPage: false,
        books: this.props.books.map(book => Object.assign({}, book, {status:"none"}))
      };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }



  handleChange=(index,event) => {
    let books = this.state.books;
    books[index].status = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ books });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.books !== nextProps.books) {
    this.setState({ books: nextProps.books.map(book => Object.assign({}, book, { status: "none" })) });
  }
}

  render() {
    return(
        <div className="app">
          {this.state.showSearchPage ? (


            <div className="search-books">
              <div className="search-books-bar">
                <a className="close-search" onClick={() => this.setState({ showSearchPage: false })}>Close</a>
                <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
                  {
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Search by title or author"/>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="search-books-results">
                <ol className="book-search">

                {<div className="book-search">
                  {this.state.books.map( (book,index) =>

                    <div key={index} className="book">
                      <div className="book-top">
                        <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193,margin:10, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail})` }}></div>
                        <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                          <select
                            value={book.status}
                            onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(book.index,event)}>
                            <option value="none" disabled>&nbsp; &nbsp; Move to...</option>
                            <option value="currentlyReading">&#x2714; Currently Reading</option>
                            <option value="wantToRead">&nbsp; &nbsp; Want to Read</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="read">&nbsp; &nbsp; Read</option>
                            <option value="none">&nbsp; &nbsp; None</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                      <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
                      <p>{book.status}</p>
                    </div>
              )}
              </div>
                }
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
// import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import './App.css'
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import BooksList from './BooksList'

class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showSearchPage: false,
    selectValue: 'None',
    books: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then((books) => {
      this.setState({ books })
      console.log(books[0])
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BooksList books={this.state.books}/>
    )
  }
}

export default BooksApp
```

So how do I write my handleChange method to get the selected array?

Edit 1: Updated the code.

So, below is the error I get in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'status' of undefined
    at BooksList._this.handleChange (BooksList.js:17)
    at Object.executeOnChange (LinkedValueUtils.js:130)
    at ReactDOMComponent._handleChange (ReactDOMSelect.js:188)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.boundFunc (ReactErrorUtils.js:63)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js:69)
    at executeDispatch (EventPluginUtils.js:83)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (EventPluginUtils.js:106)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (EventPluginHub.js:41)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (EventPluginHub.js:52)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Edit 2: Added the App.js file that contains the ComponentDidMount lifecycle method:

Comment: See if the 3 dropdown values are user specific that means user should have told you already that he/she wants to read xyz book or has read or currently reading it.

Now you should have stored those details like ids of book somewhere. You can use those details to get other details of the book from the main array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is, don't do it this way. Instead, create a smarter `books` array that holds an internal state for each individual book, and work with that:

If the books data from the API are passed as props:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  state = {
    showSearchPage: false,
    // ES7 version
    books: this.props.books.map(book => {...book, status: "none"})
    // Non-ES7 version:
    // books: this.props.books.map(book => Object.assign({}, books, { status: "none" }))
  };

  // bind the event handler to the component
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

And the dropdown event handler:

```
handleChange(index, event) {
  // grab a local copy of the book array that we will mutate
  let books = this.state.books;
  // only mutate the book that is being changed
  books[index].status = event.target.value;
  // safely pass the mutated copy into the state
  this.setState({ books });
}
```

Finally, in your render method:

```
{ this.state.books.map((book, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index} className="book">
      ...other code here...
      <select
        value={book.status}
        onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(index, event)}>
      ...rest of your code...
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Lifecycle method to handle props update:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.books !== nextProps.books) {
    this.setState({ books: nextProps.books.map(book => Object.assign({}, book, { status: "none" })) });
  }
}
```

Edit: added binding to the component's `this` to the event handler in the constructor, and changed the way the handler is passed to the onChange event.

Edit 2: Added `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook

Comment: First of all,thanks for the answer but I am not able to understand what's going on in the code.Would you mind explaining a little bit.Sorry,i am new to React and Javascript.So, if you break it a down,I would really appreciate it.

Comment: First, the books array you pass as props (and that I assume you got from an API call earlier) is "enhanced" in the constructor by turning each individual book value into an object that holds the book value and a status that is by default set to "none" (which is the default value of your dropdown). In short, we're associating a default starting status to each book. The other thing we do in the constructor is bind the event handler to the component, so that when it is called later, the `this` correctly refers to the component.

Comment: In the render method, we change the array being iterated from `this.props.books` to `this.state.books` (our enhanced array). This is important. Then, in the select element, we set the default value to whatever the current status of the book being iterated is with `value = {book.status}`. Finally, we hook our handleChange method to the onChange event, and we pass the current book index as an additional parameter.

Comment: So, for a book, if I select a value from the dropdown,that selected value will be the value of status for that particular book right? So,if I want to pass the book to a different view and remove from the main view according to the status,how can i do that?I mean i have 3 different places where the books needs to be placed according to the values selected

Comment: Finally, in the event handler `handleChange`, we create a local copy of our smart books array (remember the state itself is not directly mutable), then we update the book's status using its index and setting the value to whatever the dropdown was set to (notice the other books are unaffected, this is very important). And finally we update the state with our modified books array.

Comment: @pranami that is correct. Rendering the views is only a matter of filtering your array according to status. For example, if I want to view all the "Read" books, I can do `const readBooks = books.filter(book => book.status === "Read");`.

Comment: ohh,okay,now I get it.Thank you so much for the detailed explanations.I will try to execute it and get back again if I face any issue.I am accepting your answer.Once again, Thanks a lot.It was really helpful :)

Comment: @pranami I've made a very slight change to the way the enhanced array is built, but that syntax probably requires ES7. Let me know if that is a problem. And yes, do let me know if you face any issues, I'm sure they can be worked out. And you're welcome ;)

Comment: I am trying to implement the code and I want to display the status value of each book below the book but I am not able to see it. I am trying to show it like : <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                      <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
                      <p>{book.status}</p>

Comment: But this doesn't give me the status.Can you please check

Comment: I have edited my question above with the new code .Please have a look.

Comment: I have also mentioned the error I get from the console in the edit

Comment: Ok. 2 things: 1. I updated the way the enhanced books array is built in the constructor (see a few comments above). And 2. You need to change the array you iterate in the render function from `this.props.books` (your original array, which doesn't have status) to `this.state.books` (the enhanced array, which has status).

Comment: @pranami: `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(book.index, event)}` should be `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(null, book.index)}`. The first argument sets the `this` value and there is no `event` object at the moment the function is bound (at least it's not the one you want). [Have a look at the MDN documentation of `.bind`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Actually, it should be just `index`, and the `index` should be received as a param from the mapping function. @pranami check the code in my answer again, especially the third block.

Comment: @jaxx If I put the 3 dots before the book array in the state,it gives me an error message with Unexpected token on those dots

Comment: Then try this: `books: this.props.books.map(book => Object.assign({}, book, {status: "none"}))`. It does the same but does not require ES7.

Comment: @jaxx The error is gone wih the above code you provided.But I am facing oanother issue now.If I use {this.state.books.map( book => ...} to retrieve the books array from the API in my render method,then the array is not retrieved, but {{this.props.books.map( book => ...} works as it should.

Comment: Do you update the props after the component is mounted? Are the props updated after a search? If that's the case, you need an extra lifecycle hook, will update my answer.

Comment: @jaxx Yeah,I have an App.js file which has the componentDidMount lifecycle method which gets the books array from the API.Really sorry for not mentioning it earlier.I thought his file was not not necessary for the problem I was facing,so I didn't mention about it.So is this because of the componentDidMount lifecycle method that i am facing the present issue?And I have added the App.js file above

Comment: No. It's just that after you do a search, new props are passed to the component, which must be explicitly used to update the state (since we are transforming the books array passed in the props to an enhanced array that resides in the state). I added the required lifecycle method that should take care of it to my answer. Let me know :)

Comment: To explain precisely what is happening: When your BooksApp component first mounts the BooksList component, the API call has not yet returned data, so you initially pass an empty books array, which in turn creates an empty enhanced array in the BooksList state (from the constructor). When the API call completes, the books array is updated in the BooksApp state, and passed as props to BooksList (which is why you can iterate this.props.books in BooksList) but the state in BooksList doesn't update, and the enhanced array remains empty. The componentWillReceiveProps method should fix that.

Comment: @jaxx You are really a genius.This works.Thank you.I have one last question .Now the status is showing below the book which I was trying earlier.But if I select a different option from the dropdown,it doesnot change the status below in the <p> tag.Its always showing none in the <p> tag. How do I get the updated value of the status?

Comment: It doesn't? Then we have a problem with the onChange handler somewhere. Can you update your code again so I am up-to-date please? Thanks :) Just the BooksList component.

Comment: @jaxx I have updated BookList component above.Can you please check.

Comment: You're using `book.index` in the onChange handler, it should be just `index`.  `onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(index, event)}`.

Comment: OMG,such a silly mistake I made.Now this works like charm.Thank you so much for your time and help @jaxx.I wish I could get you a cup of coffee right now :)You are just awesome. I really wish I could code like you someday.I am just starting with Javascript and Reactjs.Really appreciate your help.Now I will try to put the books in their specific section according to the selection.I will try to do this by myself.Don't want  to bother you again.But if I am stuck,I will get back to you again with my issues. :P Anyways Thanks a lot.Have a good day :)

Comment: Glad it's all come together and working, congrats! And again, you're welcome, glad I could help :) Good luck with the rest of the project! Oh and I'll take you up on that cup of coffee offer if we ever cross paths! ;)